# Is a standard error equal to a maximum likelihood sampling distribution?

Tags: bayesian, standard-error, frequentist

Let's say we want to estimate $\mu$ in a normal model. I'm interested in the estimation error. Using R code as an example;

```
samples <- c(0, .4, .6, -2, 1, 2)
fit <- lm(samples ~ 1)
summary(fit)
```

This gives the following estimate

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.3333     0.5432   0.614    0.566
```

Now if I fit a `stan` model and sample, I obtain the following estimates

```
      mean se_mean   sd  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
mu    0.33    0.03 0.89 -1.40 -0.11  0.33  0.80  2.08  1066    1
s     1.89    0.04 1.01  0.90  1.29  1.64  2.17  4.49   776    1
```

I am using flat priors for $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so I expect the point estimate, which is the maximum likelihood estimate in both cases, to be equal, which is the case.

The standard error does not seem to be equal.

Can I interpret the standard error given by `lm` in a Bayesian / Maximum Likelihood Estimator setting? Why are they not equal?

Comment: I think you can find answer from here: http://bit.ly/2oEwfbD